# Python lxml / XPathEvalError : Invalid expression when I parse xml file

Tags: python, xml

I try to parse an XML file with lxml. It works with some files but the last one gave me an error:

```
XPathEvalError at /admin/xml_exportation/xml/add/
Invalid expression
```

Here is the xml code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<export source="Source" version="1.0" date="2014-02-21T17:46:57">
  <Agence ID="XX1" externRef="XX1" customCode="38495">
    <Biens>
      <Bien ID="XX1-176" ref="XX1-176">
        <DateMAJ>2013-06-14T12:12:07</DateMAJ>
      </Bien>
    </Biens>
  </Agence>
</export>
```

And then the python code :

```
tree = etree.parse(xml_file) 
root_path = '/export/Agence/Biens/Bien/'
for element in tree.xpath(root_path): 
   print(element)
```

I tried to change the path but it gave me the same error.

Thank you for your help.

## **EDIT**

```
Internal Server Error: /admin/xml_exportation/xml/add/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/python-envs/website.com/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in get_response
    response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/python-envs/website.com/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 372, in wrapper
    return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/python-envs/website.com/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 91, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/python-envs/website.com/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py", line 89, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/python-envs/website.com/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 202, in inner
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/python-envs/website.com/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 25, in _wrapper
    return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/python-envs/website.com/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 91, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/python-envs/website.com/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 21, in bound_func
    return func(self, *args2, **kwargs2)
  File "/home/python-envs/website.com/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/transaction.py", line 223, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/python-envs/website.com/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1007, in add_view
    self.save_model(request, new_object, form, False)
  File "/home/python-envs/website.com/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 740, in save_model
    obj.save()
  File "astucesexperts/apps/xml_exportation/models.py", line 154, in save
    for element in tree.xpath(root_path): # Find each new property
  File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 2115, in lxml.etree._ElementTree.xpath (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:57669)
  File "xpath.pxi", line 370, in lxml.etree.XPathDocumentEvaluator.__call__ (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:146579)
  File "xpath.pxi", line 238, in lxml.etree._XPathEvaluatorBase._handle_result (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:144977)
  File "xpath.pxi", line 224, in lxml.etree._XPathEvaluatorBase._raise_eval_error (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:144832)
XPathEvalError: Invalid expression
```

I also add the code from an xml file I could export with the script (changing the root path).

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<ANNONCES>
    <ANNONCE>
        <AGENCE_REF><![CDATA[22]]></AGENCE_REF>
        <AGENCE_NOM><![CDATA[Agence]]></AGENCE_NOM>
<REFERENCE><![CDATA[100lm]]></REFERENCE>
        <TRANSACTION><![CDATA[2]]></TRANSACTION>
        <TYPE><![CDATA[2]]></TYPE>
        <SOUSTYPE><![CDATA[45]]></SOUSTYPE>
        <SURFACE><![CDATA[100]]></SURFACE>
    <ANNONCE>
</ANNONCES>
```

Comment: It is helpful to include the traceback so we know which line is causing the problem.

Comment: The error means that the xpath expression `/admin/xml_exportation/xml/add/` is bad - that trailing `/` is illegal. I think the code is crashing in a different place than you show.

Comment: I used this code with another xml file and it worked.That's why I think the crash came from xml and python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XPath has a trailing '/'. Remove it and everything works as expected.

That is, change:

```
root_path = '/export/Agence/Biens/Bien/'
```

to

```
root_path = '/export/Agence/Biens/Bien'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your closing tag for `<Biens>` has no backslash, so your tree is empty because XML did not parse.

Validate your XML before you try parsing it in Python.

Comment: May just be an error when writing the question. A mismatched tag would throw an XMLSyntaxError.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Yes, it was just an error when I wrote the question.